# Can “berries” refer to types of berries?

Tags: countability

We call milk, water and wine “many liquids” when describing types of liquid. Likewise can we call blue berries, raspberries and strawberries “many berries” referring to types of berries?

Comment: I think this question is based on a misconception.  We wouldn't call milk, water, and wine "many liquids", we would just call them "liquids".  Three is much less than we usually call "many".  You could say "there are many liquids" or "there are many berries" or "there are many kinds of berries", though.

Comment: If you google 'three berry' you will find recipes for 'three berry pie', 'three berry jam' etc.  It's obvious from the context that it means 3 kinds of berry, not that the dish contains only 3 individual berries! In other contexts it might be better to say 'three kinds/types of berry'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you, mr. Bunting.

Comment: (The OP had just edited the question from 'many' to 'three' and has now changed it back again!) PS Kate is a female name!

Comment: @Kate Bunting It’s a secret between us!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It's more likely to be qualified in some way.

I think these constructions are more common:

> The pie was made with many **kinds of** berries.

> The pie was made with many **different** berries.

While this is certainly something you could say:

> The pie was made with many berries.

it is still ambiguous -- it's not clear if you mean a large *quantity* of berries or a large *variety* of berries. As a native speaker, this phrasing sounds a bit awkward in regular usage.

Comment: Then, can I say “three different berries”?

Comment: @user0203 Yes, "The pie was made with three different berries" would almost always be understood as meaning (for example) blueberries, blackberries and raspberries.